# Xcode: strict C compilation?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, compiler-construction

When I use Xcode (3.1.4 Leopard) to code in plain C (using the "Standard Tool" template that creates a "main.c"), the compiler behaves like a **C++** compiler. It allows single-line comments (like "// comment here"), it allows declaring a variable in the for-loop initializer (like "for(**int** i = 0; ...)"), it even allows inline functions (but then the linker reports that the symbol couldn't be found, great).

How can I set it to be more strict? I'm worried about accidentally writing C++ and having to correct a lot of code once I compile it on a different system.

Also, is it normal that Xcode won't auto-close brackets when you're not writing Objective C?

Thanks for any advice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those so-called "C++ features" are in fact part of C.  All three were added in C99.

If you are compiling using GCC, you can use the `-std=c89` to force the compiler into C89/C90 mode.

Comment: thank you! i didn't know that there were versions other than K&R and ANSI C. so if C99 has been around for more than 10 years, i guess it should be safe to write it :)